# why when I am using PyOpenGL for render a CubeMap I have one face in black?

Tags: python, opengl, shader, pyopengl

I am having an issue with my PyOpenGl program. I am learning so I was reading the github LearnOpenGL.
I am in topic 6. PBR sub 2.1.2.ibl_irradiance.

Trying to traduce the program but in PyOpengl. I was able to reproduce the sphere, the irradiance illumination in a good way. But I am having an issue rendering the cube map. I dont't Know Why I am having 1 side in black. (the background is in white, so I am not seeing the background. I am seeing the side but with no ilumination).
( you can check the original code en c from [here](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/3e94252892660902bef62068c35253cbe3464c9b/src/6.pbr/2.1.2.ibl_irradiance/ibl_irradiance.cpp) )
This is my code so far.

```
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader
from camera import Camera
from OpenGL.GL import *
from PIL import Image

import glfw.GLFW as GLFW_CONSTANTS
import numpy as np
import pyrr
import math
import glfw
import cv2
import glm

# settings
WIDTH = 1600
HEIGHT = 900

# camera
CAMERA = Camera( position = pyrr.vector3.Vector3( [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ) )
lastX = 800.0 / 2.0
lastY = 600.0 / 2.0
firstMouse = True

# timing
deltaTime = 0.0
lastFrame = 0.0

class Texture:

    def __init__(self, filepath, idx):

        extension = filepath.split('.')[-1]
        self.idx = idx
        self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
        
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture )
        if 'hdr' in extension:
            image = (cv2.imread(filepath, flags=cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))
            h, w, = image.shape[:2]
            image = cv2.cvtColor( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB )
            image = np.float16(image) #.flatten()
            #image_data = bytes(image.tobytes())
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image)

        else:
            with Image.open( filepath, mode = 'r') as image:
                w, h = image.size
                image = image.convert("RGBA")
                image_data = bytes(image.tobytes())
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
       
    def Use(self):
        glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + self.idx )
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        
    def Destroy(self):
        glDeleteTextures(1, (self.texture,))

sphereVAO = -1
indexCount = 0
def renderSphere():
    global sphereVAO, indexCount

    if sphereVAO == -1:
        positions = []
        uv = []
        normals = []
        
        X_SEGMENTS = 64
        Y_SEGMENTS = 64
        PI = 3.14159265359

        data = []
        for x in range(X_SEGMENTS + 1):
            for y in range(Y_SEGMENTS + 1):
                xSegment = x / X_SEGMENTS
                ySegment = y / Y_SEGMENTS
                xPos = math.cos(xSegment * 2.0 * PI) * math.sin(ySegment * PI)
                yPos = math.cos(ySegment * PI)
                zPos = math.sin(xSegment * 2.0 * PI) * math.sin(ySegment * PI)

                positions.append(pyrr.vector3.Vector3([xPos, zPos, yPos]))
                uv.append(pyrr.vector3.Vector3([ySegment, xSegment, 0]))
                normals.append(pyrr.vector3.Vector3([xPos, zPos, yPos ]))

        oddRow = False
        indices = []
        for y in range(Y_SEGMENTS):
            if not oddRow:
                for x in range(X_SEGMENTS+1):
                    indices.append( y*(X_SEGMENTS+1)+x )
                    indices.append( (y+1)*(X_SEGMENTS+1)+x )
            else:
                for x in range(X_SEGMENTS, -1, -1):
                    indices.append( (y+1)*(X_SEGMENTS+1)+x )
                    indices.append( y*(X_SEGMENTS+1)+x )
            oddRow = not oddRow

        data = []
        for i in range(len( indices )-2):
            '''
            f point1 point2 point3
            f point2 point3 point4
            f point3 point4 ...
            '''
            idx1, idx2, idx3 = indices[i:i+3]
            data += [positions[idx1].x, positions[idx1].y, positions[idx1].z, 
                     normals[idx1].x, normals[idx1].y, normals[idx1].z, 
                     uv[idx1].x, uv[idx1].y, ]
            data += [positions[idx2].x, positions[idx2].y, positions[idx2].z, 
                     normals[idx2].x, normals[idx2].y, normals[idx2].z, 
                     uv[idx2].x, uv[idx2].y, ]
            data += [positions[idx3].x, positions[idx3].y, positions[idx3].z, 
                     normals[idx3].x, normals[idx3].y, normals[idx3].z, 
                     uv[idx3].x, uv[idx3].y, ]

        data = np.array( data , np.float32 )
        indexCount = len(data) // 8
        print(data.max(), data.min(), )
        # indexCount = len( indices )

        sphereVAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        ebo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindVertexArray( sphereVAO )
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        indices = np.array(indices, dtype='uint32')
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        stride = (3 + 2 + 3) * 4

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, ctypes.c_void_p(24))
    
    else:
        glBindVertexArray(sphereVAO)
        # glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indexCount )

class Shader():

    def __init__(self, vertex_path, fragment_path):
        with open(  vertex_path, 'r') as f:
            vertex_src = f.readlines()

        with open( fragment_path, 'r') as f:
            fragment_src = f.readlines()

        self.shader = compileProgram(
            compileShader( vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
            compileShader( fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        )
        self.variables = {}

    def addMap(self, variable, texture_id ):
        glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation(self.shader, variable ), texture_id )

    def addVar( self, variable, dtype ):
        self.variables[variable] = [ glGetUniformLocation(self.shader, variable ), dtype ]

    def setValue(self, variable, values):
        assert variable in self.variables.keys(), 'Variable not founded'

        var = self.variables[variable][0]
        if self.variables[variable][1] == 'vec3':
            glUniform3fv( var, 1, values )
        elif self.variables[variable][1] == 'float':
            glUniform1f( var, values )
        elif self.variables[variable][1] == 'int':
            glUniform1i( var, values )
        elif self.variables[variable][1] == 'mat4':
            glUniformMatrix4fv( var, 1, GL_FALSE, np.float32(values) )
        elif self.variables[variable][1] == 'mat3':
            glUniformMatrix3fv( var,  1, GL_FALSE, np.float32(values) )
        else:
            print( 'error' ,  var , self.variables[variable][1] )

    def use(self ):
        glUseProgram( self.shader )

    def setVec3( self, variable , *values ):
        self.Verify( variable , 'vec3' )
        glUniform3fv( self.variables[variable][0],  1, np.array(values).astype('float32') )

    def setFloat( self, variable, values ):
        self.Verify( variable , 'float' )
        glUniform1f( self.variables[variable][0], values )

    def setInt( self, variable, value ):
        self.Verify( variable , 'int' )
        glUniform1i( self.variables[variable][0], value )

    def setMat4( self, variable , values ):
        self.Verify( variable , 'mat4' )
        glUniformMatrix4fv( self.variables[variable][0], 1, GL_FALSE, np.float32(values) )

    def setMat3( self, variable, values ):
        self.Verify( variable , 'mat3' )
        glUniformMatrix3fv( self.variables[variable][0],  1, GL_FALSE, np.float32(values) )

    def Verify( self, variable , dtype):
        if variable not in self.variables.keys(): # nueva variable
            self.addVar( variable, dtype )

def main():
    global deltaTime, lastFrame, CAMERA, lastX, lastY, firstMouse

    # glfw: initialize and configure
    glfw.init()
    glfw.window_hint(GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
    glfw.window_hint(GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_SAMPLES, 4)
    glfw.window_hint(GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

    glfw.window_hint( GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_DOUBLEBUFFER, GL_TRUE )
    window = glfw.create_window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "pyopengl", None, None)
    glfw.make_context_current(window)
    
    if window is None:
        print('Window Could not be loaded')
        glfw.terminate()

    glfw.set_framebuffer_size_callback(window, framebuffer_size_callback)
    glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, mouse_callback)
    glfw.set_scroll_callback(window, scroll_callback)

    glfw.set_input_mode(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)

    shader_pbr = Shader("shaders/2.1.2.pbr.vs", "shaders/2.1.2.pbr.fs")
    shader_rectangular = Shader("shaders/2.1.2.cubemap.vs", "shaders/2.1.2.equirectangular_to_cubemap.fs")
    shader_irradiance = Shader("shaders/2.1.2.cubemap.vs", "shaders/2.1.2.irradiance_convolution.fs")
    shader_background = Shader("shaders/2.1.2.background.vs", "shaders/2.1.2.background.fs")


    shader_pbr.use()
    shader_pbr.setInt("irradianceMap", 0)
    shader_pbr.setVec3("albedo", 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
    shader_pbr.setFloat("ao", 1.0)
    
    shader_background.use()
    shader_background.setInt("environmentMap", 0)

    lightPositions = [
        np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).astype('float32'),
    ]
    lightColors = [
        np.array([50.0, 50.0, 50.0]).astype('float32'),
    ]

    nrRows = 7
    nrColumns = 7
    spacing = 2.5

    captureFBO = glGenFramebuffers(1,)
    captureRBO = glGenRenderbuffers(1,)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, captureFBO)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, captureRBO)
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 512, 512)
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, captureRBO)

    hdrTexture = Texture( 'hdr/newport_loft.hdr', 0 )

    eye = pyrr.Vector3([ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    captureViews =  [
    # Vista 1: mirando hacia la derecha
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([1.0, 0.0, 0.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, -1.0, 0.0])),
    # Vista 2: mirando hacia la izquierda
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([-1.0, 0.0, 0.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, -1.0, 0.0])),
    # Vista 3: mirando hacia arriba
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 1.0, 0.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])),
    # Vista 4: mirando hacia abajo
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, -1.0, 0.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, -1.0])),
    # Vista 5: mirando hacia adelante
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 1.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, -1.0, 0.0])),
    # Vista 6: mirando hacia atrás
    pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at(eye, 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, -1.0]), 
                                 pyrr.Vector3([0.0, -1.0, 0.0])),
] 

    envCubemap = glGenTextures(1, )
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envCubemap)
    for i in range( len(captureViews) ):
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB16F, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, None)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    captureProjection = projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(
        fovy = 90, aspect = 1, near=0.1, far = 10, dtype = np.float32,
    )

    shader_rectangular.use()
    shader_rectangular.setInt("equirectangularMap", 0)
    shader_rectangular.setMat4("projection", captureProjection)

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hdrTexture.texture)

    glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, captureFBO)
    for i in range(len(captureViews)):
        shader_rectangular.setMat4("view", captureViews[i])
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, envCubemap, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        renderCube()
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)


    irradianceMap = glGenTextures(1,)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, irradianceMap)
    for i in range(len(captureViews)):
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB16F, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, None)
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, captureFBO)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, captureRBO)
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 32, 32)

    shader_irradiance.use()
    shader_irradiance.setInt("environmentMap", 0)
    shader_irradiance.setMat4("projection", captureProjection)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envCubemap)

    glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, captureFBO)

    # 5 abajo
    # 4 arriba
    # 3 frente
    # 2 atras

    # 1 derecha
    # 0 derecha

    for i in range(len(captureViews)):
        shader_irradiance.setMat4("view", captureViews[i])
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, irradianceMap, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        renderCube()
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    # --------------------------------------------------------------
    projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection(
            fovy = CAMERA.Zoom, aspect = WIDTH/HEIGHT, near=0.1, far = 100, dtype = np.float32, 
        )
    
    shader_pbr.use()
    shader_pbr.setMat4("projection", projection)
    shader_background.use()
    shader_background.setMat4("projection", projection)

    scrWidth, scrHeight = glfw.get_framebuffer_size(window)
    glViewport(0, 0, scrWidth, scrHeight)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):

        currentFrame = float( glfw.get_time() )
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame
        lastFrame = currentFrame
        processInput(window)

        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        shader_pbr.use()
        view = CAMERA.GetViewMatrix()
        shader_pbr.setMat4("view", view)
        shader_pbr.setVec3("camPos", CAMERA.Position )

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, irradianceMap)


        for i in range(nrRows):
            shader_pbr.setFloat("metallic", 0.8)
            for i in range(nrColumns):
                shader_pbr.setFloat("roughness", 0.2)
                model = pyrr.matrix44.create_identity()
                translation = pyrr.vector3.Vector3( [ 0, -3, 0 ] )
                model = pyrr.matrix44.multiply( m1 = model, m2 = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation( vec = translation, dtype=np.float32,) )
                model_normal = pyrr.matrix33.create_from_matrix44( model )
                model_normal = pyrr.matrix33.inverse( model_normal ).T
                
                for i , (light_pos, light_color) in enumerate(zip(lightPositions, lightColors)):
                    newPos = np.array(translation).astype('float32')
                    # newPos = np.array( [newPos[0], newPos[2], newPos[1]+1.5] ).astype('float32')
                    newPos = np.array( [0,3,0] ).astype('float32')
                    color = light_color
                    shader_pbr.setVec3("lightPositions[" + str(i) + "]",  newPos)
                    shader_pbr.setVec3("lightColors[" +str(i)+ "]", color*1 )

                    shader_pbr.setMat4("model", model)
                    shader_pbr.setMat3("normalMatrix", model_normal )
                    renderSphere()
                    break
                break
            break
            
        shader_background.use()
        shader_background.setMat4("view", view)
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envCubemap)
        renderCube()

        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

def scroll_callback( _, xoffset, yoffset ):
    CAMERA.ProcessMouseScroll( np.float32(yoffset) )

def mouse_callback( _, xposIn, yposIn):
    global firstMouse, lastX, lastY
    xpos = np.float32(xposIn)
    ypos = np.float32(yposIn)

    if firstMouse:
        lastX = xpos
        lastY = ypos
        firstMouse = False
    
    xoffset = xpos - lastX
    yoffset = lastY - ypos

    lastX = xpos
    lastY = ypos

    CAMERA.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset)

def framebuffer_size_callback():
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

def processInput(window):
    if glfw.get_key(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_PRESS:
        # global render
        # render = False
        glfw.set_window_should_close(window, True)
    if glfw.get_key(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_PRESS:
        CAMERA.ProcessKeyboard('FORWARD', deltaTime)
    if glfw.get_key(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_PRESS:
        CAMERA.ProcessKeyboard('BACKWARD', deltaTime)
    if glfw.get_key(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_PRESS:
        CAMERA.ProcessKeyboard('LEFT', deltaTime)
    if glfw.get_key(window, GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_CONSTANTS.GLFW_PRESS:
        CAMERA.ProcessKeyboard('RIGHT', deltaTime)

cubeVAO = -1
cubeVBO = 0
def renderCube():
    global cubeVAO, cubeVBO
    if (cubeVAO == -1):
        vertices = [
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0 , 1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0 
        ]

        vertices = np.array( vertices ).astype('float32')
        cubeVAO = glGenVertexArrays(1, )
        cubeVBO = glGenBuffers(1, )

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO)
        # position xp, yp, zp
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(0))

        #texture vt xt, yt
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

        # normal data nx, ny, nz
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 32, ctypes.c_void_p(24))

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
    
    else:
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And this is my camera function

```
import numpy as np
import glm
import math
import pyrr

deltaTime = 0.0
lastFrame = 0.0

# Valores por defecto de la cámara
YAW = -90.0
PITCH = 0.0
SPEED = 2.5*3
SENSITIVITY = 0.1
ZOOM = 45.0

# Clase Camera
class Camera:

    def __init__(self, position, up=None, yaw=YAW, pitch=PITCH):
        position = np.array(position).astype('float32')
        up = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0]).astype('float32')

        self.Position = position
        self.WorldUp = up
        self.Yaw = yaw
        self.Pitch = pitch
        self.MovementSpeed = SPEED
        self.MouseSensitivity = SENSITIVITY
        self.Zoom = ZOOM
        self.Front = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

        self.__updateCameraVectors()

    def GetViewMatrix(self):

        return pyrr.matrix44.create_look_at( eye = self.Position, 
                                             target = self.Position + self.Front,
                                             up = self.Up,
                                             dtype = np.float32)

    def ProcessKeyboard(self, direction, deltaTime):
        velocity = self.MovementSpeed * deltaTime
        if direction == 'FORWARD':
            self.Position += self.Front * velocity
        elif direction == 'BACKWARD':
            self.Position -= self.Front * velocity
        elif direction == 'LEFT':
            self.Position -= self.Right * velocity
        elif direction == 'RIGHT':
            self.Position += self.Right * velocity

    def ProcessMouseMovement(self, xoffset, yoffset, constrainPitch=True):
        xoffset *= self.MouseSensitivity
        yoffset *= self.MouseSensitivity

        self.Yaw -= xoffset
        self.Pitch += yoffset

        if constrainPitch:
            if self.Pitch > 89.0:
                self.Pitch = 89.0
            elif self.Pitch < -89.0:
                self.Pitch = -89.0

        self.__updateCameraVectors()

    def ProcessMouseScroll(self, yoffset):
        self.Zoom -= yoffset
        if self.Zoom < 1.0:
            self.Zoom = 1.0
        elif self.Zoom > 45.0:
            self.Zoom = 45.0

    def __updateCameraVectors(self):
        # front = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).astype('float32')
        # front.x = math.cos(np.radians(self.Yaw)) * math.cos(np.radians(self.Pitch))
        # front.y = math.sin(np.radians(self.Pitch))
        # front.z = math.sin(np.radians(self.Yaw)) * math.cos(np.radians(self.Pitch))

        self.Front = np.array(
            [
                np.cos(np.deg2rad(self.Yaw)) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(self.Pitch)),
                np.sin(np.deg2rad(self.Yaw)) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(self.Pitch)),
                np.sin(np.deg2rad(self.Pitch)),
            ]
        )
        global_up = np.array([0,0,1], dtype = np.float32)
        # self.Front = glm.normalize(front)
        self.Right = np.cross(self.Front, global_up)
        self.Up = np.cross(self.Right, self.Front)
```

this is my output. 5 faces with the hdr image but one of them in black.

[image]

In Addition I am using the shaders provided from the github Repository. I would apreciate if someone can help me seeing my error. Thank you

I want to learn more about PyOpenGL using python.